# How to scrape a dropdwon menu with Selenium-Python?

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown, scrape

I have to scrape the data from this web page: http://www.mlsa.am/?page_id=368.The webpage is in Armenian. This is a dropdown menu where the options are: Regions, Areas, Communities, Type of Subsidy, Month and Year. Once these options are selected a table shows up with information on the citizens of these places who get the different kinds of subsidies. The difficulty I am facing right now is that the second dropdown (Areas) depends on the option you select on the first dropdown and the third (Communities) depends and what you select on the previous dropdowns. How should I write my code for this type of web page?

This is how the web page looks like when you inspect it

```
<!--Մարզեր-->
            <div class="td-pb-row">
                <div class="td-pb-span2"></div>
                <div class="td-pb-span5">
                    Մարզեր <span class="ben-required">*</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select  id="ref_regions_id"  name="ref_regions" style="border:1px solid #0790A2;"  >
                        <option value="0" > Ընտրել </option>
                                                <option  value="1"> ԱՐԱԳԱԾՈՏՆ</option>
value="2"> ԱՐԱՐԱՏ</option>

    <option  value="3"> ԱՐՄԱՎԻՐ</option>

    <option  value="4"> ԳԵՂԱՐՔՈՒՆԻՔ</option>

    <option  value="5"> ԼՈՌԻ</option>

    <option  value="6"> ԿՈՏԱՅՔ</option>

    <option  value="7"> ՇԻՐԱԿ</option>

    <option  value="8"> ՍՅՈՒՆԻՔ</option>

    <option  value="9"> ՎԱՅՈՑ ՁՈՐ</option>

    <option  value="10"> ՏԱՎՈՒՇ</option>

    <option  value="11"> ԵՐԵՎԱՆ</option>`

                    </select>
                </div>
```

I am using selenium with python and so far this is my code:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\selenium-2.25.0\Driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
print("loading url into browser...")
def get_all_pages():
    payload={'value':'1'}
driver.get("http://www.mlsa.am/?page_id=368")
print(url.text)
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an option from the dropdown you showed in your HTML, I would use the `Select()` class in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ref_regions_id'))
```

Then, you can select an option as such:

```
select.select_by_text("ԱՐՄԱՎԻՐ")
```

Or, using the `value` attributes on the option elements:

```
select.select_by_value(0)
```

Lastly, you can get all available options in the dropdown:

```
options = select.options

for option in options:
    print(option)
```

To work with each dropdown depending on the previous dropdown, you'll just need to select an option for each dropdown in the correct order against a pre-determined set of options. Each dropdown has a unique ID, so that should help.

Comment: If this post helped you, feel free to mark as the answer to your problem so other users can see that it was helpful for you!